# Excel 2013: Table Slicers selection not changing values for calculated field (without VBA)

Tags: excel, slicers

I have a ODBC query in Excel that I have attached slicers to in order to filter the data.

Those slicers are on the main page along with a series of formulas to analyze the data.

i.e. Table on Sheet 2 contains rows with a unique ID, state, county, zip, and other fields.

I have Slicers on Sheet 1 that filter the data in the Table in Sheet 2. On sheet one I also have a series of calculations in Sheet 1 such as:

`=count(Sheet2!A:A)`

`=countif(Sheet2!B:B,1)/count(Sheet2!A:A)`

So with no slicers selected, the formulas should count the total in `Sheet2!A:A`, however when I select a value from the slicer to filter the table, it shows the same calculated value essentially ignoring the filters.

## Is there anyway to ensure that the calculated fields are based on the filtered data without using VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

Need to use the `SUBTOTAL` function then the corresponding function # (i.e. 2 is count, 9 is sum etc.)

so the calculation looks like this

`=count(Sheet2!A:A)` becomes `=subtotal(2,Sheet2!A:A)`